# Numpad-input for ipad using javascript

Tags: javascript, ipad

i'm looking for an easy way to make a numpad for my web-app
i have tried to make 10 `<A>`, `<INPUT>` and `<BUTTON>` with an onlick event, adding a value to the pricefield using

```
function add(v){
  document.getElementById('pricefield').value=document.getElementById('pricefield').value=v;
}
```

But it is VERY slow, and not usable for a user on ipad

Comment: Anything involving "click" handling on a touch device will be slow, because the event has to be inferred from "touch" events. Browsers are really slow about doing that. You can handler "touch" yourself or try a library like [Fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) (which itself can be a little tricky).

Comment: Why not use `<input type="tel" />` to force the numpad?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to use ontouchstart instead of onclick

thank you guys!